# 'java.lang.ClassCastException: Resource cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable'

Tags: java, exception

I have a connector which has two ports. Two ports have a common root as `Resource`. I am trying to find that common root for those two ports.

I need a set of elements for one port(p1) which can be found via `getParent` method. For the other port (p2) I need to check if any of p2's element does exist in the set. Although I need this method to return an object of type `Resource`, I am bit stuck at this point. I am getting the following error.

> Unexpected problem while loading: 'java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   policy.vddl.model.Resource cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable'
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: vddl.model.Resource cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Comparable  at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)        at
>   java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)     at
>   vddl.product.Product.findCommonRoot(Product.java:357)

```
private Element findCommonRoot(Connector connector)
{

    List<Port> portList = getListOfPort(connector);
    Port p1 = portList.get(0);
    Set<Element> portElementSet = new TreeSet<Element>();

    Element pathElement = p1.getParent();
    while (pathElement != null)
    {
        portElementSet.add(pathElement);
        pathElement = pathElement.getParent();
    }

    Port p2 = portList.get(1);
    Element pathElement2 = p2.getParent();

    for(Element e: portElementSet)
    {
        if(portElementSet.contains(pathElement2))
            pathElement2 = e;
    }

    return pathElement2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HashSet` instead `TreeSet` if don't need the elements to be sorted. `HashSet` is not sorted and doesn't need the elements to be comparable.

Answer (score 4):

`TreeSet` sorts the `Comparable` elements, So You need to make sure your Element implements `Comparable`

If you don't have access to source code of `Element` you can pass an instance of `Comparator` in the constructor of [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I didn't really need to use the TreeSet, however I agree I would have needed to implement comparable for if I used TreeSet. Using Hash set have given me the result I needed.

Comment: I am afraid I am new to posting question here. How can I mark the answer as answered?

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` is a sorted set. any `object` you add to `TreeSet` should implement `Comparable` interface. See [Java docs for add method on treeset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Element` must implement `Comparable` interface.